# Command for sharing same folder with multiple names

Tags: prompt

I’m currently working on an improvement of our deployment process and I’d really like to automate one of the new steps. Through Windows UI I can share the same folder on the network under multiple different names.
There is a prompt command for sharing (“NET SHARE _shared$=c:\Example”), but it only allows adding one shared name for the folder. Is there a prompt command for this and/or is there a way to do this programmatically, like with Windows API or even WMI?

[image: img]

Comment: I found the solution.

Thank you for your help

Comment: NET SHARE _Release1.2=C:\Users\jjs\Desktop\teste /grant:jjs,full
NET SHARE _Release1.2Beta=C:\Users\jjs\Desktop\teste /grant:jjs,full